# Configure multiple base url's in Karate

Tags: java, karate, karate-call-single

I have run a test case against multiple servers, ie Dev, QA, and STAGING. How can I configure all the URLs in the Karate configuration?

These server names are passed to Karate from the command line, using -D option

Comment: closing as exact duplicate